# How to fix CORS error when getting contents from a website?

Tags: javascript, web, header, cors, roblox

There is a CORS error in my code that gets the contents from *https://roblox.com/discover* to clone the roblox discover page.

My code:

```
<?php
   echo file_get_contents("https://www.roblox.com/discover");
?>
```

If I go to console, it says

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'robloxscript' from origin 'yoursite' has
> been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource.

**How can I go about fixing this?**

Comment: learn how to deal with CORS - though, not sure how you can deal with it when sending the contents of a web site as part of your web page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I realized that this question is over a year old and very poorly written. I had no clue about how CORS worked in javascript. You would send the requests over to your own website and proxy them, using file_get_contents("php://input") to get the necessary postfields and getallheaders() to get the necessary headers that need to be sent. You can learn more about how CORS works here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do that. Because of security reasons. Different domain. For you to be able to consume that page you will have to fetch the data using a client request and manipulate the dom to get what you want.